# how to retrive extra HTTP variables using datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables plugin for jquery and I am using the fnServerParams function.I have sent some extra variables but I am not sure how to retrieve them ont he server_processing file.

code :

```
$('#fleetsTable').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/server_processing.php",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "customerId", "value": "6" } );
    }
} );
```

this is what I have tried in the server_processing.php file

```
$customerId = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['customerId'] ) )
{
    $customerId = $_GET['customerId'] ;
}
```

this does not seem to be working..

thaks for the help

Comment: But friend the variable you named it 'name'. What you received was `$_GET['name'] = "customerID"; ` and `$_GET['value'] = "6";`

Comment: I would do a print_r($_GET); to see what you're really getting, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Andre's comment is wrong.  Datatables requires you to send parameters in the format of

```
aoData.push( { "name": "customerId", "value": "6" } );
```

This would generate a URL of:

```
../server_processing.php?customerId=6
```

in your server code,

```
$customerId = $_GET['customerId'] ;
```

should return the value.  You'll need more debugging in your php file to determine where the variable is getting lost.  Most likely a spelling mistake.